Is it possible to promote the log traces issued from a child logger under a configured root logger?
We have a few specific python modules which have most of their log traces of the form logging.debug. The owner of that source wishes the log traces to be debug, another team wishes them to be info. The root logger the second team uses sets logging.INFO as their application's logging level since there are a lot of other source modules which would flood the app's logs with debug traces if the root logger were set to that level.
Is there a way to remap log traces from a specific module to promote them from debug to info that can satisfy both clients of this code?

here's my unsuccessful attempt at this, I effectively promote the log level of the child logger but the root logger still recognizes the log traces as debug and filters them out
# Test module: first.py
import logging
from second import symbol, log_func

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def setup_logger() :
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    info_formatter = logging.Formatter( "[%(levelname)s]  %(pathname)s::%(funcName)s  %(message)s" )
    stream_handler.setFormatter(info_formatter)
    root_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    root_logger.info("Root Logging initialized")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_logger()
    logger.info(symbol)

    second_logger = logging.getLogger("second")
    logger.info(f"imported module log level before: {second_logger.level}")
    second_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.info(f"imported module log level after: {second_logger.level}")

    log_func()

#==================================================================================
# Imported module: second.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
symbol = "second_mod"


def log_func():
    logger.info(f"Log traces coming from module '{__name__}'")
    logger.debug("this is debug level") # <--------- how to get this trace visible??
    logger.info("this is info level")

this code yields the following console output
$ python first.py 
[INFO]  first.py::setup_logger  Root Logging initialized
[INFO]  first.py::<module>  second_mod
[INFO]  first.py::<module>  imported module log level before: 0
[INFO]  first.py::<module>  imported module log level after: 10
[INFO]  second.py::log_func  Log traces coming from module 'second'
[INFO]  second.py::log_func  this is info level

I know the logging hierarchy bubbles all the log traces from down below up to the root logger, which filters from above it all. However is there a way to effectively remap the log traces that are statically authored in a given module over to something else?
